# Static Generic methods in .Net vs Java

Tags: java, c#, android, .net, generics

I am unsure about something.

In C#, I can do the following.

```
public class Helper<T> where T : new()
{
    public static T SomeHelperFunction(string strValue)
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

Here, the static method can clearly make use of the type passed through to the `Helper` class.

Here is my exact attempt in Java/Android

```
public class Helper<T> {
    public static T SomeHelperFunction(String strValue){
        //some code
    }
}
```

Java complains about the T used in the `SomeHelperFunction`.  Why does .Net allow this, but not Java, or am I missing something?

How can I create the .Net class in Java?

Comment: What about `public static <T> T SomeHelperFunction(String strValue)`? See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html.

Comment: It would help if you also included the exact error message you get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this

```
public class Helper<T> {
public static <T> T SomeHelperFunction(String strValue){
    //some code
}
}
```

In Java , Static generic methods need their own generic declaration;

Comment: If I pass the type to the Helper class, will the type automatically be inferred on the static method?

Comment: Doesn't need to be `class Helper<T>` in that case; just `class Helper`

Comment: @khelwood The question is explicitely related to if the generic type-param is inherited from the class itself, so although it´s not really needed in this example it fits the questions settings.

Comment: The use of class parameter `T` was a bad idea here since it is in opposition to the correctness of the answer. The use of the same symbol `T` for the generic parameter of the `static` method is horrid practice as it leads to great confusion. Terrible answer and worse justification for its flaws. Downvoted.